# Simple Python Q: idk what produces None when this code's executed

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I'm just learning Python by reading a book and the following code was used to show the try and except commands. Those make sense, but my question is about the output. When executed, after the spam(0) produces an error, it says None on the following line, which is then followed by 42. Where's the None come from?

```
def spam(divideBy):
    try:
        return 42 / divideBy
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Error')

print(spam(2))
print(spam(12))
print(spam(0))
print(spam(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, functions that don't have a `return` statement return `None`. So the exception is caught and the function returns, and then the next line executes.

If the `except` block raised the exception again, then the function would not return, but would throw an exception instead.

Comment: Ah, I learned that last chapter but was thrown off because spam was defined with a return statement. Thanks for clearing this up for me!